# How to get all children of the children of the specific parent

Tags: mysql, binary-tree

I want to query all the children of the children of the specific parent

```
ID | PARENTID | NAME
1  | 1        | STEVEN
2  | 1        | CARL
3  | 1        | LUIS
4  | 1        | ELLA
5  | 1        | RYAN
6  | 2        | SHEILA
7  | 3        | CARLA
8  | 4        | IRIS
9  | 5        | CRIS
10 | 100      | ALLAN
11 | 6        | STEVEN
12 | 11       | DIANA
```

Comment: Any effort thus far?

Answer (score -1):

it would be helpful if you could show what you've tried thusfar, but basically:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE parentid in (SELECT id from table where parentid = X and id <> X)
```